# Making my application crash more gracefully

Tags: android

I have an app that is running pretty stably (no more crashes actually), but as everybody knows your program crashes as soon as it gets in the hands of somebody else :D

What I would like is to find a(all) the place(s) where I can put a try{}catch(){} to be able catch and control what happens when the app crashes unexpectedly (display a better message, send log, possible recovery...)

I know its surely not that simple but still it would be good if there was a way to catch most of them.

(for example there is a small bug in GLSurfaceView that when it is being closed causes sometimes to crash because of an EGL swap buffer)

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at this article: http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/10/07/programmers-notebook-uncaught-exception-handlers/

But be careful when using this, you might mask errors in your application and if you resort to this to just pretend your app is working, you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: I know that its not the right way, my main intent is to be able to get logs in the field (offering to the user a way to notify me when the app has crashed rather than the good old "your application has stopped unexpectedly, sucks to be you"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *really* lazy way to catch any given exception:

```
try {
  //do some stuff here
} catch (Throwable e) {
  //handle exception here
}
```

This is useful if you have no idea what's going to be thrown. Consequently, it's not going to be very helpful for any kind of recovery. This is something I wouldn't use beyond the testing period of development.

Comment: I know it is lazy and shouldn't be done at all. for the moment I don't have any project of putting a recovery system that way. I'm 100% sure of my code because I busted my ass tracking down every and any big or small bug that ever popped up during dev and beta testing across 5 different android phones. but I've been a programmer long enough to know that no program is 100% sure ever. and where would you put the try catch because there is no main function which launches everything ^^

Comment: You'd probably have to put it around each statement where you'd want to handle an exception, as you can only get one exception per try/catch block-- the remainder of the try block will not be executed after an exception occurs. More mess :)